# case when sums returning null values

Tags: sql, sum, case, amazon-redshift

I've written the following temp table to set up for a case when sum query.

Total_count_package_5_15 and total_count_package_5_13 are both returning null values. (They shouldn't be). The data is properly set up in the preceding temporary table and I've confirmed that the data is there as expected.

```
create temporary table screening_packages_count_2018 as

select screening_screen_date,
       count(case when screening_package = 1 then 1 end) as count_package_1,
       count(case when screening_package = 2 then 1 end) as count_package_2,
       count(case when screening_package = 3 then 1 end) as count_package_3,
       count(case when screening_package = 4 then 1 end) as count_package_4

from prod.leasing_fact

where date_part(year, screening_screen_date) = 2018

group by screening_screen_date

order by 1;


-- 5 AND 6 PACKAGE TOTALS BASED ON 2018 1-4 COUNTS

    select date_trunc('day', screening_screen_date)                                              as day,
           case
               when (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3) <= 75)
                   then (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) end as total_count_package_5_15,

           case
               when ((sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) >= 76 and
                     (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) <= 150)
                   then (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) end as total_count_package_5_13,

           0                                                                                     as total_count_package_6

    from screening_packages_count_2018

    where count_package_4 = 0
    group by day
```

I believe that there is an error in my case statement when using sums, but I'm not sure what is going on here. Thanks!

Comment: I would put an `ELSE 0` in the first `Select` for each `COUNT() function`. If there are any `NULL` values, you can't `SUM` NULL values. But I could be wrong.

Comment: ok, added that. I'm now getting `0` for each line, instead of null. Should be data.

Comment: Can you post data to support your results? Also, does the `Where count_package_4 = 0` have anything to do with your `0` results?

Comment: nevermind. :) it's fixed. thank you!

Comment: @aks85 . . . If the question is no longer valid, then delete it.

Comment: @WEI_DBA's solution was the correct one.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then... I'm assuming the 1 vote on my first comment is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... Put an `ELSE 0` in the first `Select` for each `Count() function`. If there are any `NULL` values, you can't `SUM NULL` values.

```
create temporary table screening_packages_count_2018 as

select screening_screen_date,
       count(case when screening_package = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as count_package_1,
       count(case when screening_package = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as count_package_2,
       count(case when screening_package = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as count_package_3,
       count(case when screening_package = 4 then 1 ELSE 0 end) as count_package_4

from prod.leasing_fact

where date_part(year, screening_screen_date) = 2018

group by screening_screen_date

order by 1;


-- 5 AND 6 PACKAGE TOTALS BASED ON 2018 1-4 COUNTS

    select date_trunc('day', screening_screen_date)                                              as day,
           case
               when (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3) <= 75)
                   then (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) end as total_count_package_5_15,

           case
               when ((sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) >= 76 and
                     (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) <= 150)
                   then (sum(count_package_1) + sum(count_package_2) + sum(count_package_3)) end as total_count_package_5_13,

           0                                                                                     as total_count_package_6

    from screening_packages_count_2018

    where count_package_4 = 0
    group by day
```